# NullPointerException on my amateur benchmark program

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
import java.io.*;
class threads extends Thread{
    int counter=0;
    static volatile boolean counting=true;
    public void run(){
        if(counting) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
public class cores {
    static PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
    @SuppressWarnings({ "static-access", "deprecation" })
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        int mastercounter=0;
        Thread mainthread=Thread.currentThread();
        int cores= Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();      
        threads[] array=new threads[cores];
        for (int x=0;x<cores;x++) {
            threads t=array[x];
            t.start();
        }
        mainthread.sleep(5000);
        threads.counting=false;
        for (int x=0;x<cores;x++) {
            threads t=array[x];
            t.stop();
            mastercounter+=t.counter;
        }
        pw.println(mastercounter);
    }
```

The code above is my attempt at a simple benchmark program that tries to take advantage of all cores available on the CPU of a computer by simply using all the threads possible to count in 5 seconds.
The code gives a `NullPointerException` on the line `t.start()` which I assume is because of the way I tried to work around not being able to name variables dynamically.
Any advice, fixes or tips are much appreciated.

Comment: @Hover Should probably be "how to initialize an array of objects"

Comment: @cricket_007: I'll ask SOCVR to close this question in a few days

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oh! The Miolnir! The Miolnir! So, isn't this just another NPE? Which you wouldn't consider a duplicate? The Miolnir! The Miolnir! Incoherence made human.

Comment: @NoiseGenerator: This exactly illustrates my point.. Notice that the NPE Q/A used to close this question was not the usual NPE question but rather one more specific to NPE and reference arrays. Always better to close with a more specific duplicate if possible.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels NPEs are NPEs. That's my point of view. The more generic, the best. Since you will learn to handle a wider range of them

Answer (score 0):

```
threads[] array=new threads[cores];
```

You create new array of type `threads` which is never assigned any value, as `threads` is a class the array itself is an array that holds references. Default value for the array of references is `null`, when you call:

```
t.start();
```

you are invoking `start()` method on a `null` value, therefore you get `NullPointerException`. You need to initialize your array before assigning values in it and calling methods on those values.

Answer (score 0):

Your array has no elements. `threads t=array[x];` will of course be null.

Try to make some objects, and please capitalize your classes

```
array[x] = new Threads();
array[x].start();
```